# How to remove event listener after adding

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove an Event listener from my button after I add an event listener, most like overriding the previous code, but it isn't working, I tried to console log, but it gives `undefined`, not sure why. What am I doing wrong/missing?

app.js

```
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector(".dialog").style.display = "block"
    setTimeout(()=>{
        document.querySelector(".dialog").style.display = "none"
    }, 2500)
})
document.querySelector("button").removeEventListener("click", sayHi);
function sayHi(){
    console.log('hello')
}
```

index.html

```
    <div class="container">
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate in illo omnis vitae molestias natus eaque necessitatibus molestiae nesciunt illum!
        <button>find out more</button>
    </div>

    <div class="dialog" style="display: none;">
        <div class="context">
            <h1>Hi!</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

app.css

```
.container{
    width:500px;
    height: auto;
    margin:0 auto;
}
button{
    margin:20px auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dialog{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.context{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: white;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) - the issue is, you've added one function and trying to remove a different function - that's not how event listeners work - read the docs to understand

Comment: It might make more sense to just disable the button than remove the listener.

Comment: @Andy good point, actually I wanted to recreate a problem which is minified version of this, now I want to know if I do not know the event name, how would I remove an event from it.

Comment: You can't. If you read the documentation @Bravo provided you need to know the event, and the function reference/function provided as the handler, to be able to remove the listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep the reference to the function you want to remove like this:

```
function popup(){
    document.querySelector(".dialog").style.display = "block"
    setTimeout(()=>{
        document.querySelector(".dialog").style.display = "none"
    }, 2500)
}
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", popup)
document.querySelector("button").removeEventListener("click", popup);
```

and the reason is `removeEventListener` needs to know exactly which function to  remove from the `target element` events, because you can add a lot of functions to the same event, and if you want to remove one you have to say which one

Comment: thanks, but why wasn't it working before, why do we need to keep a reference?

Comment: @localhost that's because `removeEventListener` needs to know exactly which function to  remove from the `target element` events, because you can add a lot of functions to the same event and if you want to remove one you have to say which

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a named function instead of anonymous function. also you need to trigger the `removeEventListener` in some way

Fixed Code

```
const showDialog = ()=>{
        document.querySelector(".dialog").style.display = "block"
        setTimeout(()=>{
            document.querySelector(".dialog").style.display = "none"
        }, 2500)
    }

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", showDialog)


//code required to remove event listener
//document.querySelector("button").removeEventListener("click", showDialog);
document.querySelector("#remove_button").addEventListener("click", ()=>{
document.querySelector("button").removeEventListener("click", showDialog);
})
```

I have created a basic codepen for you to play around with
https://codepen.io/jaydave1412/pen/vYWVmLo

Comment: What if we don't know the event name, e.g. if the code is minified and no access to unminified file, can we remove the event?

Comment: well, in that case use can use the `getEventListener` method available in chrome devtools. It will not work in your javascript file but if you have access to the functionality of javascript file you can just add that to your webpage and find the events, however if the eventlistener implementation in that minified javascript file uses anonymous functions to implement events then there is nothing you can do.